# XMLReader not reading in all elements requested

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

So I have this XML

```
<entry>
<id>ABC123</id>
<title type="text">title </title>
<author xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <name>test.com</name>
</author>
<link rel="self" href="http://www.test.com/asdasd.html"/>
<updated>2012-07-04T06:12:15.337</updated>
<content type="xml">
    <listing systemId="thesystemid" url="www.myurl.com">
        <description>
            This is a description
        </description>
    </listing>
</content>
</entry>
```

I'm using XMLReader with this code and I'm pulling in the data using this:

```
$url = $product->content->listing['url'];
$id = $product->id;
$name = $product->title;
$desc = $product->content->listing->description;
```

Everything is being pulled in perfectly apart from $desc

$product has been set as 'entry'

I just cannot see why, any ideas?

Error is

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in......
```

Cheers

Comment: Added the error to the post :)

Comment: I think description is missing for some elements.. can u check this ?

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
$aa= '<entry>
     <id>ABC123</id>
     <title type="text">title </title>
     <author xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
     <name>test.com</name>
     </author>
     <link rel="self" href="http://www.test.com/asdasd.html"/>
     <updated>2012-07-04T06:12:15.337</updated>
     <content type="xml">
     <listing systemId="thesystemid" url="www.myurl.com">
     <description>
        This is a description
     </description>
     </listing>
     </content>
     </entry>';
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($aa);
  echo $xml->content->listing->description;
```

This will work. Enjoy.